Multiple classes found for path "xxx" in the registry of this declarative base
I define two model inherit from sqlmodel.SQLModel, all of them come from differentdatabase but their table name is same, I define them in different module, but has an error,
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Table 'xxx' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.

I define different metadata for them to resolve this error.I want to find another way to resolve it.
Another one is, when I use sqlmodel.Relationship,  has another error
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Multiple classes found for path "User" in the registry of this declarative base. Please use a fully module-qualified path

I try to write the whole path to resolve it, for example, 'xx.xx.User' or 'xx.xx.OneUser', but also can not resolve it.
The code is follow
# user1.py
from sqlmodel import Field, SQLModel, Index, Relationship, MetaData
from .role import Role
base1 = MetaData()

class User(SQLModel, table=True):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    metaData = base1
    id: int = Field(primary_key=True)
    role_id: int = Field(description="role id")

    role: Optional[Role] = Relationship(
        back_populates='users',
        sa_relationship_kwargs={"primaryjoin": "foreign(User.role_id) == remote(Role.id)"}
    )

# user2.py
from sqlmodel import Field, SQLModel, Index, Relationship, MetaData
from .role import Role
base2 = MetaData()

class User(SQLModel, table=True):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    metaData = base2
    id: int = Field(primary_key=True)
    name: str

The above code is only an example, and the two users tables come from different databases
hope can resolve sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Multiple classes found for path "User" in the registry of this declarative base. Please use a fully module-qualified path. this error, and find another way exclude define different metadata to resolve sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Table 'xxx' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object..
Thanks for your help
